# ¿Cómo ejecutar archivo de python con el programador de tareas y mantener idle abierto?

Tags: python, windows

Tengo una tarea programada en el programador de tareas de windows, que me abre un archivo .bat con el siguiente codigo:

```
@ECHO OFF

START "" "D:\Proyectos\Tablero\ejecucion.py"
```

este bat sirve para ejecutar el archivo ejecucion.py.  Pero cuando el archivo .py se ejecuta y termina se cierra inmediatamente.  Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de mantener la ventana abierta y así ver los logs que esta generando., me refiero a lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿es posible que esto no se cierre?

Comment: Una posibilidad sería agregar en el .bat un última instrucción pidiendo que el usuario de Enter.

Answer (score 0):

pudes hacerlo haciendo una redireccion de tu ejecucion a un archivo de log
ejemplo:

```
START "" "D:\Proyectos\Tablero\ejecucion.py" >> C:\data\data.log
```

aunque prefiero hacerlo directo desde python

```
### codigo de mi programa
### almacenamos todo en una variable data

with open("C:\data\data.log","a") as f:
    f.write(data)
    f.flush()
```

abrimos una ventana **cmd** escribimos **powershell** y ejecutamos el siguiente comando:

windows:

```
Get-Content C:\data\data.log -wait
```

linux

```
tail -f /data/data.log
```

ahora solo seria esperar que se ejecute el codigo python agrege contenido al log
y se ira mostrando en pantalla.
[image: ejemplo]
saludos.

Answer (score 0):

A tu archivo .bat, al final agrega `PAUSE`

algo asi.

```
@ECHO OFF

START "" "D:\Proyectos\Tablero\ejecucion.py"
PAUSE
```

Comment: hola Carlos buenas tardes, mil gracias por responder.... Este funciona, pero el genera la pausa en el cmd y esta abriendo el idle de python para ejecutarlo, y ese es el que se cierra.

Answer (score 0):

Y qué tal incluir una función dentro del script `ejecucion.py` que escribe un log y te olvidas de esa ventana siempre abierta

```
import os, time

# ... 

def write_log(ruta, msg):
    log_filename = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.log", time.localtime())
    actualtime = time.strftime("[%H:%M:%S] ", time.localtime())
    new_line = actualtime + msg + " \n"
    with open(os.path.join(ruta, log_filename), 'a') as f:
        f.write(new_line)
```

Si le envías data a esa función, especificándole una ruta y un mensaje, por ejemplo:

```
lines = '''Linea 1
Linea 2'''
write_log('C:/Temp', lines)
```

Escribirá un archivo de log diario en `C:/Temp` con nombre:

```
2021-07-30.log
2021-07-31.log
etc...
```

Internamente cada archivo tendrá un log parecido a esto:

```
[12:58:06] Linea 1
Linea 2 
[13:05:10] Linea 1
Linea 2 
etc...
```

Comment: Hola aeportugal.  muchas gracias por tu respuesta.  Me parece super intersante esta opcion que me compartes, Aunque me genera una inquietud, y es que ya el programa esta generando los logs  como podría replicar esos logs en la función.